# Как в PhpStorm скопировать код в цвете в буфер обмена (чтобы вставить в Excel или Word)

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день.
Гуру, подскажите, может кто сталкивался с проблемой.
Храню заготовки в Excel, ранее пользовался Notepad++, в нём есть плагин для копирования кода с подсветкой. Возможно что-то подобное есть и в PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте плагин [Copy on Steroids](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7198).

Comment: да, спасибо, как раз уже установил, погуглил на инглише, выдало сразу
очень хороший плагин, всем советую http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7198. Качаете по ссылке Jar-файл, заходите в PhpStorm в File - Settings - Plugins - Instal Plugin from disk. Вуаля - и код у вас копируется в цвете!